# Cannot start Apache application after deployment on Windows

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

Trying to deploy Midpoint OpenSource IDM software on Windows server
Runing JAVA 9.0.1 and Tomcat Apache 8.5

Deployment of the WAR file seems to succeed but application does not start

On Tomcat Web Application Manager I get the error:

```
FAIL - Application at context path [/midpoint] could not be started
```

In the Catalina logs all I can see is:

```
SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-38] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-38] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/midpoint] startup failed due to previous errors
```

Comment: I recommend you to change from Java 9 to Java 7 or 8 to run Tomcat 8 to see if the error continues. Check this page for seeing which Java version to which Tomcat http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

Comment: Thanks @pringi , I ended up reinstalling JAVA and Tomcat and I noticed, I messed up one of the configuration files of the app. Changed "/" by "\" .. Beginner's mistake :)
I did follow your advice though and installed Java 8 instead.